# Access MasterPage Control through App_Code Shared Procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

**Background:** At present I have a control `<div id="TransactionStatus" runat="server" class="StatusBarCSS">God is Great!</div>` in the `MasterPage.master` file  to display the transaction status. The status is updated from `ChildPage1.aspx` using the function (*refer Code 1*). Things are fine if the below code remains in the ChildPage.

**Code 1**

```
Private Sub PrinTransactionStatus(ByVal intMode As Integer, ByVal strMessage As String)

    Dim objStatus As HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("TransactionStatus"), HtmlGenericControl)

    If objStatus Is Nothing Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        ' if the mode is 0 which means Error
        If intMode = 0 Then
            objStatus.Visible = True
            objStatus.InnerHtml = "<b>Error: </b></span>" + strMessage.ToString()
            objStatus.Style.Add("border-color", "red")
            objStatus.Style.Add("background-color", "rgb(255, 242, 242)")
            objStatus.Style.Add("color", "#000;")
        ElseIf intMode = 1 Then
            objStatus.Visible = True
            objStatus.InnerHtml = "<b>Success: </b></span>" + strMessage.ToString()
            objStatus.Style.Add("border-color", "green")
            objStatus.Style.Add("background-color", "rgb(244, 255, 230)")
            objStatus.Style.Add("color", "#000;")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Need Expertise:** Since the above code will be used by many pages, I moved the entire code to App_Code folder as a Public Shared procedure but now the code is not working anymore.
System is indicating error as `Master` is not declared.

What am I missing here or doing wrong..Appreciate

Just to add, I already have `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SubPagesMaster.master" %>` in the `ChildPage1.aspx`

Comment: Try passing a reference to the master page into the `PrinTransactionStatus` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting it in a shared procedure make a base web page class and put the method in there.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace MyNameSpace
  Public Class MyBaseWebPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub PrinTransactionStatus(ByVal intMode As Integer, ByVal strMessage As String)

        Dim objStatus As HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("TransactionStatus"), HtmlGenericControl)

        If objStatus Is Nothing Then
            ' do nothing
        Else
            ' if the mode is 0 which means Error
            If intMode = 0 Then
                objStatus.Visible = True
                objStatus.InnerHtml = "<b>Error: </b></span>" + strMessage.ToString()
                objStatus.Style.Add("border-color", "red")
                objStatus.Style.Add("background-color", "rgb(255, 242, 242)")
                objStatus.Style.Add("color", "#000;")
            ElseIf intMode = 1 Then
                objStatus.Visible = True
                objStatus.InnerHtml = "<b>Success: </b></span>" + strMessage.ToString()
                objStatus.Style.Add("border-color", "green")
                objStatus.Style.Add("background-color", "rgb(244, 255, 230)")
                objStatus.Style.Add("color", "#000;")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

In each of you web page code behinds change the Inherits to reference this page.  Then you can reference the method from the code behind.

```
Partial Class Default2
 Inherits MyNameSpace.MyBaseWebPage


 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.PrinTransactionStatus(1, "message")
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Worked like butter. One thing to confirm, do I still need to declare `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SubPagesMaster.master" %>` in the ChildPages

Comment: @YashmanGupta.  I am not sure but I don't think so.  You are not directly referencing anything in the master.  You could always just try it without and see if it still works.

Comment: Thanks, due to this article by MS [How to: Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xxwa0ff0(v=vs.100).aspx), I asked, will try